# App become unresposive and crashes eventually

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a functionality where a user can click multiple photos and save it(done using camera2 api). I want to update the count of images taken from `ImageAvailableListener`. I had written a method to updateUI in my camera fragment using `Activity.RunOnUiThread`. I am assuming that it is because of `RunOnUiThread` that my app becomes unresponsive and crashes.

Below is the code:

**ImageAvailableListener**

```
public class ImageAvailableListener : Java.Lang.Object, ImageReader.IOnImageAvailableListener
{
    public ImageAvailableListener(CameraFragment fragment)//, File file)
    {
        if (fragment == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("fragment");

        owner = fragment;
    }

    private readonly File file;
    private readonly CameraFragment owner;

    public void OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
    {
        owner.mBackgroundHandler.Post(new AddImageToList(reader.AcquireNextImage(), owner));//, owner.mFile));
    }

    private class AddImageToList : Java.Lang.Object, IRunnable
    {
        private CameraFragment fragment;
        private Image mImage;
        public AddImageToList(Image image, CameraFragment _fragment)
        {
            if (image == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("image");

            mImage = image;
            fragment = _fragment;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
                buffer.Get(bytes);
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
                fragment.capturedPicBase64.Add(new Data.Models.ViewModel.DocumentImageViewModel { imgName = string.Format("{0}", guid), base64 = base64String });//base64String);
                fragment.updateUICount();
                mImage.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Camera Fragment**

```
public class CameraFragment : Frag, View.IOnClickListener, FragmentCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
{
    private static readonly SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    public static readonly int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static readonly string FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    // Tag for the {@link Log}.
    private static readonly string TAG = "CameraFragment";

    // Camera state: Showing camera preview.
    public const int STATE_PREVIEW = 0;

    // Camera state: Waiting for the focus to be locked.
    public const int STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1;

    // Camera state: Waiting for the exposure to be precapture state.
    public const int STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2;

    //Camera state: Waiting for the exposure state to be something other than precapture.
    public const int STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3;

    // Camera state: Picture was taken.
    public const int STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4;

    // Max preview width that is guaranteed by Camera2 API
    private static readonly int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;

    // Max preview height that is guaranteed by Camera2 API
    private static readonly int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;

    // TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener handles several lifecycle events on a TextureView
    private SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener;

    // ID of the current {@link CameraDevice}.
    private string mCameraId;

    // An AutoFitTextureView for camera preview
    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;

    // A {@link CameraCaptureSession } for camera preview.
    public CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;

    // A reference to the opened CameraDevice
    public CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    // The size of the camera preview
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    // CameraDevice.StateListener is called when a CameraDevice changes its state
    private CameraStateListener mStateCallback;

    // An additional thread for running tasks that shouldn't block the UI.
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    // A {@link Handler} for running tasks in the background.
    public Handler mBackgroundHandler;

    // An {@link ImageReader} that handles still image capture.
    private ImageReader mImageReader;

    // This is the output file for our picture.

    public List<ImageViewModel> capturedPicBase64 { get; set; } = new List<ImageViewModel>();

    // This a callback object for the {@link ImageReader}. "onImageAvailable" will be called when a
    // still image is ready to be saved.
    private ImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener;

    //{@link CaptureRequest.Builder} for the camera preview
    public CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;

    // {@link CaptureRequest} generated by {@link #mPreviewRequestBuilder}
    public CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;

    // The current state of camera state for taking pictures.
    public int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;

    // A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.
    public Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

    // Whether the current camera device supports Flash or not.
    private bool mFlashSupported;

    // Orientation of the camera sensor
    private int mSensorOrientation;

    // A {@link CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback} that handles events related to JPEG capture.
    public CameraCaptureListener mCaptureCallback;

    // Shows a {@link Toast} on the UI thread.
    public void ShowToast(string text)
    {
        if (Activity != null)
        {
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(new ShowToastRunnable(Activity.ApplicationContext, text));
        }
    }

    private class ShowToastRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, IRunnable
    {
        private string text;
        private Context context;

        public ShowToastRunnable(Context context, string text)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }

    public void updateUICount()
    {
        if (Activity != null)
        {
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                _shootMP = null;
                AudioManager meng = (AudioManager)Activity.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
                int volume = meng.GetStreamVolume(Stream.Notification);

                if (volume != 0)
                {
                    if (_shootMP == null)
                        _shootMP = MediaPlayer.Create(Activity, Uri.Parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"));
                    if (_shootMP != null)
                        _shootMP.Start();
                }

                maximumPics++;
                if (maximumPics > 0)
                {
                    count.Text = string.Format("({0})", maximumPics);
                    back.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    done.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    back.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    done.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private static Size ChooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
        int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio)
    {
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        var bigEnough = new List<Size>();
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are smaller than the preview Surface
        var notBigEnough = new List<Size>();
        int w = aspectRatio.Width;
        int h = aspectRatio.Height;

        for (var i = 0; i < choices.Length; i++)
        {
            Size option = choices[i];
            if ((option.Width <= maxWidth) && (option.Height <= maxHeight) &&
                   option.Height == option.Width * h / w)
            {
                if (option.Width >= textureViewWidth &&
                    option.Height >= textureViewHeight)
                {
                    bigEnough.Add(option);
                }
                else
                {
                    notBigEnough.Add(option);
                }
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those big enough. If there is no one big enough, pick the
        // largest of those not big enough.
        if (bigEnough.Count > 0)
        {
            return (Size)Collections.Min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        }
        else if (notBigEnough.Count > 0)
        {
            return (Size)Collections.Max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        }
        else
        {
           // Log.Error(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    public static CameraFragment NewInstance()
    {
        return new CameraFragment();
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        capturedPicBase64 = Activities.ViewActivity._documentImageViewModel;

        mStateCallback = new CameraStateListener(this);
        mSurfaceTextureListener = new SurfaceTextureListener(this);
        // fill ORIENTATIONS list
        ORIENTATIONS.Append((int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.Append((int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.Append((int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.Append((int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270, 180);
    }
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.cameraFragment, container, false);
    }

    public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.texture);
        view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.picture).SetOnClickListener(this);
        done = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.done);
        done.Click += CameraFragment_Click;
        count = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.count);
        back = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.back);
        back.Click += Back_Click;
        if (Activities.ViewActivity.finalImageViewModel.Count - 1 > 0)
        {
            maximumPics = Activities.ViewActivity.finalImageViewModel.Count - 1;
            count.Text = string.Format("({0})", maximumPics);
        }
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        capturedPicBase64=null;
        capturedPics = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activity.Finish();
    }

    private void CameraFragment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activities.ViewActivity.finalImageViewModel.AddRange(capturedPicBase64);
        Activity.Finish();
        Intent _viewActivity = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ViewActivity));
        StartActivity(_viewActivity);
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureListener(this);
        mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageAvailableListener(this);//, mFile);
    }

    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        StartBackgroundThread();

        // When the screen is turned off and turned back on, the SurfaceTexture is already
        // available, and "onSurfaceTextureAvailable" will not be called. In that case, we can open
        // a camera and start preview from here (otherwise, we wait until the surface is ready in
        // the SurfaceTextureListener).
        if (mTextureView.IsAvailable)
        {
            OpenCamera(mTextureView.Width, mTextureView.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            mTextureView.SurfaceTextureListener = mSurfaceTextureListener;
        }
    }

    public override void OnPause()
    {
        CloseCamera();
        StopBackgroundThread();
        base.OnPause();
    }

    private void RequestCameraPermission()
    {
        if (FragmentCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera))
        {
            new ConfirmationDialog().Show(ChildFragmentManager, FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
        else
        {
            FragmentCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera },
                    REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    public void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
            return;

        if (grantResults.Length != 1 || grantResults[0] != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
           // ErrorDialog.NewInstance(GetString(Resource.String.request_permission))
              //      .Show(ChildFragmentManager, FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }


    // Sets up member variables related to camera.
    private void SetUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height)
    {
        var activity = Activity;
        var manager = (CameraManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < manager.GetCameraIdList().Length; i++)
            {
                var cameraId = manager.GetCameraIdList()[i];
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                var facing = (Integer)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensFacing);
                if (facing != null && facing == (Integer.ValueOf((int)LensFacing.Front)))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var map = (StreamConfigurationMap)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ScalerStreamConfigurationMap);
                if (map == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = (Size)Collections.Max(Arrays.AsList(map.GetOutputSizes((int)ImageFormatType.Jpeg)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(largest.Width, largest.Height, ImageFormatType.Jpeg, /*maxImages*/2);
                mImageReader.SetOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                // coordinate.
                var displayRotation = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = (int)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.SensorOrientation);
                bool swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation)
                {
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270)
                        {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180)
                        {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        //Log.Error(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                        break;
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetSize(displaySize);
                var rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                var rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                var maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.X;
                var maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.Y;

                if (swappedDimensions)
                {
                    rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                    rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                    maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.Y;
                    maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.X;
                }

                if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH)
                {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT)
                {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }

                // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
                // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                // garbage capture data.
                mPreviewSize = ChooseOptimalSize(map.GetOutputSizes(Class.FromType(typeof(SurfaceTexture))),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                    maxPreviewHeight, largest);

                // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
                var orientation = Resources.Configuration.Orientation;
                if (orientation == Orientation.Landscape)
                {
                    mTextureView.SetAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.Width, mPreviewSize.Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    mTextureView.SetAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.Height, mPreviewSize.Width);
                }

                // Check if the flash is supported.
                var available = (Boolean)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.FlashInfoAvailable);
                if (available == null)
                {
                    mFlashSupported = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    mFlashSupported = (bool)available;
                }

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
           // ErrorDialog.NewInstance(GetString(Resource.String.camera_error)).Show(ChildFragmentManager, FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    // Opens the camera specified by {@link CameraFragment #mCameraId}.
    public void OpenCamera(int width, int height)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Activity, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestCameraPermission();
            return;
        }
        SetUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
        ConfigureTransform(width, height);
        var activity = Activity;
        var manager = (CameraManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
        try
        {
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.TryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.Milliseconds))
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            manager.OpenCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
        }
    }

    // Closes the current {@link CameraDevice}.
    private void CloseCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.Acquire();
            if (null != mCaptureSession)
            {
                mCaptureSession.Close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            if (null != mCameraDevice)
            {
                mCameraDevice.Close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mImageReader)
            {
                mImageReader.Close();
                mImageReader = null;
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.Release();
        }
    }

    // Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
    private void StartBackgroundThread()
    {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.Start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.Looper);
    }

    // Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
    private void StopBackgroundThread()
    {
        mBackgroundThread.QuitSafely();
        try
        {
            mBackgroundThread.Join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Creates a new {@link CameraCaptureSession} for camera preview.
    public void CreateCameraPreviewSession()
    {
        try
        {
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.SurfaceTexture;
            if (texture == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("texture is null");
            }

            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.SetDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.Width, mPreviewSize.Height);

            // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.CreateCaptureRequest(CameraTemplate.Preview);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.AddTarget(surface);

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            List<Surface> surfaces = new List<Surface>();
            surfaces.Add(surface);
            surfaces.Add(mImageReader.Surface);
            mCameraDevice.CreateCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSessionCallback(this), null);

        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static T Cast<T>(Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
    {
        var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
    }

    // Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix}
    // transformation to `mTextureView`.
    // This method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in
    // setUpCameraOutputs and also the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.

    public void ConfigureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight)
    {
        Activity activity = Activity;
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity)
        {
            return;
        }
        var rotation = (int)activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.Height, mPreviewSize.Width);
        float centerX = viewRect.CenterX();
        float centerY = viewRect.CenterY();
        if ((int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90 == rotation || (int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270 == rotation)
        {
            bufferRect.Offset(centerX - bufferRect.CenterX(), centerY - bufferRect.CenterY());
            matrix.SetRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.Fill);
            float scale = Math.Max((float)viewHeight / mPreviewSize.Height, (float)viewWidth / mPreviewSize.Width);
            matrix.PostScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.PostRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        }
        else if ((int)SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180 == rotation)
        {
            matrix.PostRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.SetTransform(matrix);
    }

    // Initiate a still image capture.
    private void TakePicture()
    {
        try
        {
            if (maximumPics < 10)//(capturedPics.Count + 1 <= 10)
            {
                LockFocus();
            }
            else
            {
                ShowAlert("Maximum 10 images are allowed.");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void restartFocus()
    {
        try
        {
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(
                CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger
                , (int)ControlAFTrigger.Cancel); //CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
            if (mCaptureSession != null)
            {
                mCaptureSession.Capture(
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build(),
                    mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
            }

        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Lock the focus as the first step for a still image capture.
    private void LockFocus()
    {
        try
        {
            // This is how to tell the camera to lock focus.

            mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger, (int)ControlAFTrigger.Start);
            // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the lock.
            mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
            if (mCaptureSession != null)
            {
                mCaptureSession.Capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback,
                        mBackgroundHandler);
            }
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Run the precapture sequence for capturing a still image. This method should be called when
    // we get a response in {@link #mCaptureCallback} from {@link #lockFocus()}.
    public void RunPrecaptureSequence()
    {
        try
        {
            // This is how to tell the camera to trigger.
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAePrecaptureTrigger, (int)ControlAEPrecaptureTrigger.Start);
            // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the precapture sequence to be set.
            mState = STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE;
            mCaptureSession.Capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private CaptureRequest.Builder stillCaptureBuilder;
    private TextView count;
    private TextView back;
    private ImageView done;
    private int maximumPics;
    private MediaPlayer _shootMP;

    // private int countOfPictures=0;

    public File _dir { get; set; }

    // Capture a still picture. This method should be called when we get a response in
    // {@link #mCaptureCallback} from both {@link #lockFocus()}.
    public void CaptureStillPicture()
    {
        try
        {
            var activity = Activity;
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice)
            {
                return;
            }
            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            if (stillCaptureBuilder == null)
                stillCaptureBuilder = mCameraDevice.CreateCaptureRequest(CameraTemplate.StillCapture);

            stillCaptureBuilder.AddTarget(mImageReader.Surface);

            // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            stillCaptureBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfMode, (int)ControlAFMode.ContinuousPicture);
            SetAutoFlash(stillCaptureBuilder);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = (int)activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;
            stillCaptureBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.JpegOrientation, GetOrientation(rotation));

            mCaptureSession.StopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.Capture(stillCaptureBuilder.Build(), new CameraCaptureStillPictureSessionCallback(this), null);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Retrieves the JPEG orientation from the specified screen rotation.
    private int GetOrientation(int rotation)
    {
        // Sensor orientation is 90 for most devices, or 270 for some devices (eg. Nexus 5X)
        // We have to take that into account and rotate JPEG properly.
        // For devices with orientation of 90, we simply return our mapping from ORIENTATIONS.
        // For devices with orientation of 270, we need to rotate the JPEG 180 degrees.
        return (ORIENTATIONS.Get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    }

    // Unlock the focus. This method should be called when still image capture sequence is
    // finished.
    public void UnlockFocus()
    {
        try
        {
            // Reset the auto-focus trigger
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger, (int)ControlAFTrigger.Cancel);
            SetAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

            // After this, the camera will go back to the normal state of preview.
            if (mCaptureSession != null)
            {
                mCaptureSession.Capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build(), mCaptureCallback,
                  mBackgroundHandler);
                mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
                mCaptureSession.SetRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback,
                        mBackgroundHandler);
            }
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.Id == Resource.Id.picture)
        {
            TakePicture();
        }
    }

    public void SetAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder)
    {
        if (mFlashSupported)
        {
            requestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAeMode, (int)ControlAEMode.OnAutoFlash);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I update UI from runnable()? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18332093/1650891) has the similar issue as of mine.

Link to device log :[deviceLog](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=92905595378887662079)

Comment: What your crash log says?

Comment: what happends if you do not run it on ui thread? the only thing that stands out to me right awya is _shootMP = MediaPlayer.Create(Activity, Uri.Parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg")); perhaps this line can be run outside of ui thread? or perhaps there is even an issue with read and write permissions. Logcat would help

Comment: Added a link to device log. Please take a look.

Comment: If I do not run it in UI thread then count label is not getting updated. And yes I can put _shootMP = MediaPlayer.Create(Activity, Uri.Parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg"));  outside of RunOnUiThread. But will that help?

Comment: I think here _Uri.Parse("file:///system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg")_ is error. Because while you reading this you need to use _FileProvider_ if your target version _>=26_